# Kendo UI for Angular: how to define min-width in grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

In this Kendo UI for Angular grid I defined the columns with `width: 100px`. What I need now is to define the columns with `min-width` instead of `width`. Is this possible?

```
<kendo-grid 

    [kendoGridBinding]="data"
    [resizable]="true"
    [sortable]="true"
    filterable="menu">
    
    <kendo-grid-column
        *ngFor="let col of columns"
        [title]="col.title"
        field="{{col.field}}"
        filter="{{col.filter}}"
        [width]="100"
        [class]="{'alignRight': col.alignRight }">
    </kendo-grid-column>

</kendo-grid>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try using [minresizablewidth](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/ColumnComponent/#toc-minresizablewidth) input property like:

```
<kendo-grid 

[kendoGridBinding]="data"
[resizable]="true"
[sortable]="true"
filterable="menu">

<kendo-grid-column
    *ngFor="let col of columns"
    [title]="col.title"
    field="{{col.field}}"
    filter="{{col.filter}}"
    [width]="100"
    [minResizableWidth]="80"
    [class]="{'alignRight': col.alignRight }">
</kendo-grid-column>
```

to make sure that the user cannot resize the column by using the UI (not less than 80px in the example).